# Ibatis SQl error Correct syntax for Substring

Tags: sql, ibatis

Running an insert

`SUBSTRING(#[].SomeColumnName#,1,18)` doesn't work but
`#[].SomeColumnName#` is valid syntax but substring doesn't seem to like it ..
What is the valid syntax for substring in this case?

on another query
`SUBSTRING(#SomeColumnName#,1,18)` does work.

Comment: What is the **actual** error message you get?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use iBatis and not MyBatis? iBatis is retired since 2010.